# passing a value of a clicked button within the same blade - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm passing the following variable to the blade:

```
@foreach($stampreq as $stampreq)
<a href="" class="stamp_acc">Accept</a>
```

When clicking the above button, a jquery code runs to open a modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="stamp_fb">
```

I want to pass the following id to Ajax when the button is clicked :

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "pstusrId"  id="pstusrId" value="{{ $stampreq->id }}">
```

I'm receiving an error "Trying to get property of non-object" because $stampreq is an array (has more than one record).
 How can I pass the `$stampreq->id` of the clicked button to the `<input>` tag to be sent to AJAX ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error "Trying to get property of non-object" because you are using the same name between the collection and the individual looped variable (`$stampreq`) within your foreach method, the value in your input is potentially pulling from the collection / array.  Thus, it isn't seeing the looped variable, but rather the array.

To fix, change the variable to something different (either the array or the loop variable):

```
@foreach($stampreq as $stampreq)
```

to

```
@foreach($stampreqSomethingPlural as $stampreq)
```

Or

```
@foreach($stempreq as $stampreqLoop)
  <button class="stamp_acc" value="{{ $stampreqLoop->id }}" data-id="{{ $stampreqLoop->id }}">Accept</button>
```

I have removed the `<a>` and made it all in one button.  This way, you can access the `id` from within your AJAX call using `$(this)` if you like.

Then, in your input within the loop, you can now successfully call the id from your looped variable (and add it to a data element if you wish to pull from AJAX later):

```
 <input type = "hidden" name = "pstusrId"  id="pstusrId" value="{{ $stampreqLoop->id }}" data="{{ $stampreqLooop->id }}">
```

Comment: I changed the single $stampreq  to $stampreq1 , but now I'm receiving (Undefined variable: stampreq1). Does the hidden tag has to be inside the @foreach loop ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to know **which** `$stampreq` was clicked.  The reason for the Undefined var is likely that you didn't match in the foreach AND in the input area.  So, check the following:  1) `@foreach($plural as $stampreq)`  2) Your controller names` $plural` as `$plural`, else you get undefined var.  OR if you name the second variable, the loop variable then you must match the new name in the input when calling `->id`

Comment: So I will put one input tag inside the loop, and the other one will be normally inside the Modal HTML, right ?

Comment: Well... two different things really.  You need to know the ID of the `$stampreqLoop` on your AJAX call.  Within AJAX, you'll have something like `var id = $(this).data('stampId')` and then send that back to your controller so that the controller can send the right `$stampreq` back to your modal.  You will have the `$stampreq` variable in the modal from AJAX, so you don't need the input there.  While this is not the original question (which I think we solved), I do recommend you change that input from an `<a>` to a button - Let me edit again :)